# @Html.Dropdownlist(x => x.id, new int) not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

How i can make this work

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>MYep @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, new int {
                          new SelectListItem() {Text = "asdad", Value = "1"},
                          new SelectListItem() {Text = "dfgdgd", Value = "2"},
                          new SelectListItem() {Text = "werwrwt", Value = "3"}, "Choose")

<input type="submit" value="Ok" />
```

}

Or should I make a IEnumerable list before and give it to dropdownlistfor?

Answer (score 2):

Matt's answer is fine, but it looks like you are using a ViewModel, so you should just put this static list into the view model and reference the list in your View.

**ViewModel**:

```
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> IdList
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem> 
            { 
                new SelectListItem { Text = "asdad", Value = "1" }, 
                new SelectListItem { Text = "dfgdgd", Value = "2" }, 
                new SelectListItem { Text = "werwrwt", Value = "3" } 
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, Model.IdList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an object of type `int` and populating it with a List of `SelectListItem`s, which will not work.

I think you want something like this...  You may have to make some modifications if x.Id is an int and all the dropdown values are strings, but I'm not sure.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, new List<SelectListItem> {                          
      new SelectListItem() {Text = "asdad", Value = "1"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = "dfgdgd", Value = "2"},
      new SelectListItem() {Text = "werwrwt", Value = "3"}}, "Choose")
```

Comment: I just need that value 1,2 or 3 to pass back to controller so it does not really matter how its done, but what ive read that should be IEnumerable i think

Comment: List implements IEnumerable so you can use it.  You can't instantiate an interface, so new IEnumerable<T>() just plain won't work.